# Getter and ManyToOne relationship doesn't work

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder, doctrine-query

I'm working on a symfony project and I have an entity (calling here ent) with several attribute one of them being a ManyToOne relationship:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="RB\ABundle\Entity\Somethingelse", inversedBy="ent")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false, onDelete="CASCADE")
 */
private $smthg
```

Now in my controller i have a getter :

```
public function getAction($smthg)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $ents = $em->getRepository('ABundle:Ent')
        ->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->where('p.smthg = :smthg')
        ->setParameter('smthg', $smthg)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getArrayResult();
    return new JsonResponse($ents);
}
```

My getter works great except that i don't get all the attribute with ManyToOne relationship

I tried things like that :

```
public function getAction($smthg)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $ents = $em->getRepository('ABundle:Ent')
        ->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->select('p')
        ->join('p.smthg','pr')
        ->where('p.smthg = :smthg')
        ->setParameter('smthg', $smthg)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getArrayResult();
    return new JsonResponse($ents);
}
```

But it doesn't displays what's in the database for the 'smthg'.

PS: in the database i have the right information. They are there, i just can't get them.

Thanks for the help

Comment: What does it mean doesn't works? $ent doesn0t exist, il would be $ents

Comment: it's not that, just bad rewriting here but not this error in my code

Comment: ok but specify what does It mean doesn't works, returns error? wrong results?

Comment: It is a lazy loading issue.  ->select('p','pr')

Comment: @Cerad Well it works thanks. You answered first but a guy put the answer so if you want to put it i'll confirm yours. If not i'll confirm his

Comment: Go ahead and accept his.  He took the time to give you a complete solution.  A few words of explanation would have been nice but oh well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public function getAction($smthg)
{
    $ents = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('ABundle:Ent')
        ->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->select('p', 'pr')
        ->join('p.smthg','pr')
        ->where('p.smthg = :smthg')
        ->setParameter('smthg', $smthg)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getArrayResult();
    return new JsonResponse($ents);
}
```